# How to create multilevel Category tree from same table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, treeview, categories

How to create multilevel Category tree from same table in Laravel. I may have 2 level categories or may be up to 5th level Subcategories and I want this dynamic in Laravel.

For example-

```
  Category 1
            |_ Subcat 1-1
            |_ Subcat 1-2

  Category 2 
            |_Subcat 2-1
            |        |_Subcat 2-1-1
            |        |      |_ Subcat 2-1-1-1
            |        |      |_ Subcat 2-1-1-2
            |        |
            |        |_Subcat 2-1-2
            |
            |_Subcat 2-2 

  Category 3
```

Comment: can you show table structure and also Category model

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce parent_id column in your table

For items at the first level , the the id and parent_id is simillar

CategoriesTable { id ,name,parent_id }

Here is how the data is stored in the table

```
id , name , parent_id    
1 , Books , 1
2 , Clothes ,2
3 , counterbook,1
4 , jeans , 2 
5 , cars,5
```

The chain can go on and on , so in your foreach loop you have put an if id = parent_id then you know to determine 1st level

Comment: Be sure to write separate migration files if you intend to add constraints to the parent_id column.

incase you need sample code for looping through and plotting categories at all levels kindly let me know